# How do I make changes in one ObservableCollection trigger a notification in another ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

In my C# application, I have two `ObservableCollection` properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<Material> Materials { get; init; } = new();

public ObservableCollection<string> MaterialNames
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> names = new();

        foreach (Material material in Materials)
        {
            names.Add(material.Name);
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

The second property shadows the first one, returning `Name` from the objects in the first list. A WPF `ListBox` is binded to this second property. What I need is for the second list to fire an update when members are added or removed from the first one, so that the `ListBox`  updates. Right now, that doesn't happen. What is the easiest solution to implement this, "connecting" the notifications of both ObservableCollections?

Disclaimer: I know it is easier to bind to the first property and set `DisplayMemberPath` to `Name`, but due to certain constrains in the application I need to bind to a separate property.

Comment: You should definitely get rid of those "*constraints in the application*".

Comment: @Clemens I would if I could, but currently it is outside my control. For now, I have to make do with linking these notifications as a sort of a patchwork solution.

Comment: You can subscribe to CollectionChanged event of the first ObservableCollection and add/remove the items of the second ObservableCollection when each event fires.

Comment: @emoacht, thank you, but where exactly would I do the subscribing? This class that holds both properties is a data structure, which has to be serialized and de-serialized with JSON converter, which is set up to ignore any constructors in this class (it causes issues, like duplicates in the list when deserialized), so what is the best place to place that subscription code?

Comment: Both are public properties that are accessible from outside the class. You can attach a CollectionChanged handler wherever you like. We can't tell where exactly, because we do not know your code.

Comment: "You should definitely get rid of those "constraints in the application" Must be nice to have such power over time and space.

Comment: Unless we know the details of those constraints, we can only say that it would be a trivial modification in the UI code. The MaterialNames property is entirely redundant and should just not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to use an immutable collection as the source, and just replace the entire collections when needed. All changes must be done by replacing the immutable collection.

```
private ImmutableArray<Materials> MyMaterials{
   get => myMaterials;
   set{
       myMaterials = value;
       Materials = new ObservableCollection<Material>(value);
       MaterialNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(value.Select(m => m.Name));
       OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
public ObservableCollection<Material> Materials {
   get => ...
   set => ...
}
public ObservableCollection<string> MaterialNames  {
   get => ...
   set => ...
}
```

You *can* do things like projecting changes from one list to another, just listen to `CollectionChanged` and replicate the changes to your other collection. But I find it fairly difficult to figure out exactly what have changed. So my personal preference is to use a custom list with more informative events I  can use to replicate changes to a ObservableCollection.

If you need to serialize this data I would recommend creating separate "Data Transfer Objects" (DTOs) that only includes plain lists/arrays that can be handled by the serialization library. You can then create your UI model from this. That way you are not mixing UI concerns with serialization concerns.

But the better solution is almost certainly to address whatever issues that prevent you from just using `DisplayMemberPath`

Comment: Materials and MaterialNames would not need to be ObservableCollections here. You must however make sure that their property setters also call OnPropertyChanged().

Comment: Besides that, figuring out what exactly has changed is simple. You get all necessary information by the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs of the CollectionChanged event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This could work. I like the DTO suggestion too, but the question then becomes - how do I avoid having to essentially duplicate every member of DTO in the UI model, since as I understand it is shadowing the DTO  (plus UI concern logic for each property)? Also, doesn't that mean that each shadowing UI model item still has to bind to the DTO properties, so that if these properties are changed internally by the application, the shadowing UI model properties get notified and propagate the change to the UI?

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas You will need to duplicate properties and have code to copy properties between your DTO and UI model. This is the cost of using DTOs, but your DTO would not need to contain "materialNames" for example. You should not have any synchronization between the model and DTO. When you load data you deserialize the DTO and update the UI model. Whenever you want to save you create a DTO from the UI model and serialize it. But you can trigger a "save" whenever the UI-model changes, if that is the behavior you want

Comment: @JonasH Okay, but in such implementation, what if just a single element of the DTO is modified internally by the application rather than the user (for example, the value of a property), how will the UI model get notified about this change so that the UI model and the UI itself updates instantly, like it does with direct binding that I have right now?

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas DTOs are *short lived* objects that are *only* used for serialization/communication. So it should not be modified internally.

Answer (score 0):

Overall I think your implementation is wrong.
The ListBox should be bound to the Materials collection, but only display the Name Material property. Therefore, the MaterialNames collection is redundant.

But I thought it would be interesting to implement the binding you need. Here is my implementation. Check it out.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace Core2023.SO.Justinas_Rubinovas
{
    public class BindingCollections
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Material> Materials { get; } = new();

        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> MaterialNames { get; }
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _materialNames = new();

        public BindingCollections()
        {
            MaterialNames = new(_materialNames);
            Materials.CollectionChanged += OnMaterialsChanged;
        }

        private void OnMaterialsChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    _ = e.NewItems ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
                    {
                        for (int i = e.NewItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            _materialNames.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex, ((Material?)e.NewItems[i])?.Name ?? string.Empty);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    _ = e.NewItems ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
                    {
                        if (e.NewStartingIndex < e.OldStartingIndex)
                            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                            {
                                _materialNames.Move(e.OldStartingIndex + i, e.NewStartingIndex + i);
                            }
                        else if (e.NewStartingIndex > e.OldStartingIndex)
                            for (int i = e.NewItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                            {
                                _materialNames.Move(e.OldStartingIndex + i, e.NewStartingIndex + i);
                            }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    _ = e.OldItems ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
                    {
                        for (int i = e.OldItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            _materialNames.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    _ = e.NewItems ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            _materialNames[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = ((Material?)e.NewItems[i])?.Name ?? string.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        for (; i < Materials.Count && i < _materialNames.Count; i++)
                        {
                            _materialNames[i] = Materials[i].Name;
                        }
                        for (; i < Materials.Count; i++)
                        {
                            _materialNames.Add(Materials[i].Name);
                        }
                        for (; i < _materialNames.Count;)
                        {
                            _materialNames.RemoveAt(_materialNames.Count - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();

            }
        }
    }

    public class Material
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this solution, on first glance it should work, and I will test it.  As for your first comment, the reason why I can't have ListBox display the name like you suggested, is because it's ItemsSource has to be binded to a String type property, not just display a string property, since the SelectedItem of that ListBox is binded to a model data object property of type String, not Material. Therefore, I created MaterialNames property to act as a converter, so that from that point onward everything is done with String type properties, not Material.

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas You just missed the correct approach. Instead of binding SelectedItem, bind SelectedValue and set SelectedValuePath appropriately, like DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: @Clemens that makes sense, I didn't know it is possible to do it like this. Thank you, I will rewrite this as per your suggestion.